# How to prove that the interpreter is /bin/bash when called from cron?

Tags: bash, cron

That has been a bit of a puzzle for me.

When I try the following cronjobs individually:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -c "readlink /proc/$$/exe >> /root/printenv"
* * * * * /bin/bash -c "readlink /proc/$PPID/exe >> /root/printenv"
* * * * * /bin/bash -c "readlink /proc/self/exe >> /root/printenv"
* * * * * /bin/bash -c "ps -h -o comm -p $$ >> /root/printenv"
* * * * * /bin/bash -c "echo $SHELL" >> /root/printenv
```

I get the following results respectively:

```
/bin/dash
/usr/sbin/cron
/bin/readlink
sh
/bin/sh
```

I can't seem to have it report `/bin/bash` in any circumstances when called from cron like that.

In a direct cronjob `* * * * * /bin/bash -c "command"` how can I prove that "`command`" is being interpreted by `/bin/bash` (if it is) ?

**Answer for future references**:

Changing the double quote for a single quote returned the right shell:

`* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe >> /root/printenv'`

Returned:

`/bin/bash`

Thanks to all contributors to the answer below.

Comment: Interesting.  I think when you use bash -c, it changes the effective interpreter to whatever the executable being called in -c is.  So, you have cron, which is using `/bin/sh` as it's SHELL, calling `/bin/bash` with `-c somecommand`, which in turn is exec'ing that 'somecommand'.  So effectively `somecommand` is becoming the ps of record.

Comment: Also stracing crond might worth a try. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case my default shell is `bash` and I just ran a test:

```
sh -c 'echo $0'
```

result: `sh`

```
sh -c "echo $0"
```

result: `-bash`

```
 bash -c 'echo $0'
```

result: `bash`

```
 bash -c "echo $0"
```

result: `-bash`

it looks like you need to use single quotes `'` followed by the `-c` switch

Comment: The single quotes would be the key there I think.  The `$$` would be expanded before the `bash` shell starts otherwise, so they'd always be reporting on the "outer" process

Comment: Yes.  single quotes passes a literal string, whereas double quotes will pass a shell interpreted string.

Comment: @EricRenouf: You were right, it was the single quote!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with all your commands is that you're using the wrong quote. Each command in crontab is a snippet of shell code, which is processed by a shell. The crontab command processing shell is defined by the setting of the `SHELL` variable in the crontab file, defaulting to `/bin/sh`.

When `/bin/sh` (or any compatible shell) executes the script `/bin/bash -c "readlink /proc/$$/exe >> /root/printenv"`, one of the steps after parsing the command line is to perform any variable or command substitutions. There is one variable substitution here: the `$$` which is inside a double-quoted string. So `$$` is replaced by the process ID of the `/bin/sh` process. Say this process ID is 1234. The shell invoked by cron executes the command `/bin/bash` with the arguments `-c` and `readlink /proc/1234/exe >> /root/printenv`. The output indicates that `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`.

If you use single quotes instead of double quotes, then the shell invoked by cron does not perform any variable substitution, and executes the command `/bin/bash` with the arguments `-c` and `readlink /proc/$$/exe >> /root/printenv`. Bash then parses this command, performs the substitution of `$$` with its own process ID, and executes `readlink` with the argument `1234`.

Note that depending on the shell, the output of that command might not be the shell binary, it could be `/bin/readlink`. The reason is that there is an optimization in bash (and several other shells): when the last thing the shell has to do is to run an external command, it doesn't run that command in a child process, it replaces the shell's process image. (Executing a program under Unix always works by [replacing the process image with another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)); programs [usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec) [duplicate themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) just before doing that but it isn't an obligation.) Since bash detects that running `readlink` is the last thing it has to do, it runs `readlink` in the same process 1234, so `readlink /proc/1234/exe` reports `/bin/readlink`. Bash performs this optimization if you just run a command

```
bash -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe`
```

but not if there's a redirection on it. Some shells (e.g. dash) don't perform this optimization. Some shells, such as ksh, are a little cleverer and optimize `ksh -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe >>/root/printenv`, but wouldn't optimize e.g. `ksh -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe; true`. (Exercise: why is it impossible to optimize that one?)

Comment: is there a difference between calling `bash -c` and `/foo/myscript.sh` with bash shebang from a crontab?

Comment: @MichaelD. Very few. Running bash on a script file keeps the script file open on a file descriptor. A few variables (`BASH_EXECUTION_STRING, `BASH_SOURCE`) have different values.

Comment: thanks, so in your given example `readlink` will still be optimized in the script and not run as a child process?